# pyautogui p.typewrite self loop

Tags: python

im trying to make a program that has a small chance of changing what the user preseed on their keyboard.

lets say 1% of any key they press will send another key to os.

The problem is when it happen it write the actual key pressed and the random new key, when the new random key is virtualy pressed the "on_press" detect it as a user input and start to loop into itself sending lots of input to the os.

I have tried it with pynput and got about the same result.

Is there another way to write it or make it work somehow?

Thanks.

here is the code but with 50% change to change the input so it's easier to check it.

```
import pyautogui as p
import random
from random import seed, randint
import string
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

seed(randint)


def randletter(stringLength=1):
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    randletter1 = random.choice(letters)
    return randletter1


def on_press(key):
    randomnum = randint(0, 100)
    if randomnum > 49:
        pass
    else:
        p.typewrite(randletter())


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        listner.stop()
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listner:
    listner.join()
```